# I Can not issueidentities in Hyperledger composer from a Business network

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I can transact with the network, and create new assets and participants but if I true to issue an identity based on the participant I get.

```
Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors 
[[{"code":0,"message":"Registration of '4770' failed in affiliation 
validation: : scode: 401, local code: 44, local msg: Caller does not 
have authority to act on affiliation 'org1', remote code: 20, remote msg: Authorization failure"}]]
```

Where do I begin to debug this issue. I am using the IBM Enterprise Blockchain system for doing deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer identity issue` defaults to the `org1` affiliation if no affiliation is supplied on the command. To specify your own affiliation you need to add the option `-o affiliation=xyz` (where xyz is a valid affiliation defined in your fabric ca server). For example

`composer identity issue -c admin@network -u newuser -a org.example.mynetwork.Person#P1 -o affiliation=myaffiliation`

Note that being able to provide an affiliation in playground is not possible.

Comment: First of all thank you, second can you provide me a link to documentation that would allow me to determine which affiliations are valid.

Comment: Like if I used yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork to create a business network what affiliation would be acceptable in that network.

Comment: I understand this is probably a stupid question but if I search of HypeLedger  Composer for affiliation it return no results. 

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/search/search.html?query=affiliation

Comment: Would it be in the connection.json file that IBM allows me to download from the server.

Comment: Unfortunately this option is missing from our documentation at the moment. I would assume that there would be somewhere either in the connection details you download or elsewhere within the web UI that defines what affiliations exist. Affiliations exist only in the fabric ca server, and don't have any meaning for business networks. So you would define a user under an affiliation, and you get a secret back. With that user name and secret you can then request an identity and create a card with that identity, or create a card with that name and secret.